# Greater than, Less than with negative numbers

Tags: .net, vb.net

Hello I am having trouble with the greater than less than function in vb.net. It works flawlessly with positive numbers but will not work with the negative numbers. Here is my code I hope this helps.

```
Dim A, B, input As Integer
A = (-38)
B = (-173)
txtD.Text = CStr(CInt(txtD.Text))
input = CInt(txtD.Text)

If input <= 32 < CInt(A) Then
    txtR.Text = "Water will freeze and Oxygen will boil at this Temperature"
ElseIf input <= CInt(A) > CInt(B) Then
    txtR.Text = "Water and Mercury will Freeze and Oxygen will boil at this temperature"
End If
```

Comment: You haven't given an example of your input, expected result and actual result. I would also personally recommend expressing a single condition at a time and using `AndAlso` (or whatever) to combine them - it's not clear to me (as a simple C# developer) how `input <= CInt(A) > CInt(B)` is meant to be evaluated.

Comment: (It's also not clear why you're using `CInt(A)` and `CInt(B)` when they're already integers.)

Comment: Note that if you had `Option Strict` on, you'd have received an error message already due to the problems with the code. I strongly recommend that you start using `Option Strict`...

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, your code is syntactically wrong:

```
If input <= 32 < CInt(A) Then
     txtR.Text = "Water will freeze and Oxygen will boil at this Temperature"
ElseIf input <= CInt(A) > CInt(B) Then
     txtR.Text = "Water and Mercury will Freeze and Oxygen will boil at this temperature"
End If
```

Needs to include another statement such as `And` or `Or` depending what you're attempting to achieve.

For example:

```
 ElseIf input <= CInt(A) And input > CInt(B) Then
```

However based upon what variable `A` and `B` are set to these won't evaluate to true.

As an additional note:

```
txtD.Text = CStr(CInt(txtD.Text))
```

Is a pointless statement.

`txtD.Text` returns a string therefore there is no need to convert it to an integer, and then a string and then assign it to itself.  Simply remove this.

Also, `A` and `B` are already integers, you don't have to cast them to integers by using `CInt`.  Simply use the variable `A` and `B` directly.

Answer (score 0):

You need `And` to join your conditions.

Something like

```
     If input <= 32 And 32 < CInt(A) Then
          txtR.Text = "Water will freeze and Oxygen ..."
     ElseIf input <= CInt(A) And  CInt(A) > CInt(B) Then
          txtR.Text = "Water and Mercury will Freeze and Oxygen will ..."
     End If
```

Comment: I feel this would have been a great time to introduce a newbie to using 'AndAlso' instead of 'And' to avoid a common pitfall with VB.Net. What do you think?